# Power Point with audio

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint presentation to create, but I want to voice over the details of the presentation.  How do I do this?  Also, is there a way to enhance my voice in the process?  I have a very soft voice that would make babies sleep!

Answer (score 1):

PowerPoint has a Record Presentation feature that might help.

A decent external microphone will give better results than the built-in one, if you have one of those. PowerPoint won't give any options to enhance your voice, though. For that, you'd probably want to record the audio in a separate program like Audacity (free), split the finished audio file up into per-slide chunks, then insert them into your PPT.

I have a free add-in that does a lot of the grunt work and includes a tutorial on how to make it simpler yet with Audacity. Windows PPT only, though the Audacity tips would work with Mac Audacity.

http://www.pptools.com/free/FAQ00004-PPTools-Narrator.htm

The download gives you a free limited (to five slides) demo version. If it's helpful, contact me via the link on the site and request a free registration key.